# Given integers $M, N$, the integer triple $(a, b, c)$ solution to $M = a + b + c$ and $N = a \times b \times c$ is unique iff...?

Tags: number-theory

Suppose we are given integers $M$ and $N$, and the equations:

$$ M = a + b + c $$

$$ N = a \times b \times c $$

where $a, b, c$ **are integers as well**. This point, regarding the allowable solutions being integers, and not real numbers in general, is crucial because it prevents us from using relatively easy theories for real solutions, where one need only match the number of constraints to the number of variables?

So, is the solution to these equations, the *integer* triple $a, b, c$ unique, given what we have said so far?

Clearly not. After all, suppose we had $M = 4$ and $N = 0$, then both $0, 1, 3$ and $0, 2, 2$ are both solutions.

We could put down as a constraint: $a \neq 0, b \neq 0, c \neq 0$. Or, we could put down: $a \neq b, b \neq c, a \neq c$.

Do I need both constraints to force a unique solution? Just one? Or do I still need further constraints in addition to these?

What mathematical theory can I use to figure out how many constraints I need to force a unique solution?

Comment: Instead of constraining $a$, $b$ and $c$, how about constraining $M$ and $N$ to be nonzero?

Comment: Any time you find a solution, you can permute the values of $a,b,c$ to get other solutions (assuming that the three values aren't all equal).

Answer (score 1):

You need more constraints. For instance

$1+8+12=21=2+3+16$ and

$1\cdot 8\cdot 12 = 96 = 2\cdot 3\cdot 16$

Comment: But what mathematical theory can I use to confirm when it is I have enough constraints?

Comment: That seems to be a different question than what you originally asked. What makes you think that there are such constraints available?

Comment: I clarified the question then: really, I want to figure out what the relevant mathematical theory is.